# Is there a way to use box-shadow with blur in css?

Tags: css

I'm sorry for title `use box-shadow with blur` but I don't know what is this technique called:

Css on facebook:

[image: 1]

The bottom can be blurred, I've tried to use:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px -7px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
```

But the result was not same:

[image: 2]

What's it called and how can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Trev14 said, it uses a linear gradient. Here is their CSS:

```
._5r8l .uiScrollableArea.contentAfter:after {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .05), #fff);
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: It's working, I've added `width, height, content, margin-top, position (absolute)` based on your advice. It's really working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like they actually had a white gradient at the bottom with 100% opacity fading quickly to 0% opacity. Give that a shot and see how you like it.